# Map optional parameter in Web API C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I am using `Postman` to make a `Get` call. In the `URL` I have optional parameters with `underscore` in it. I want to assign those values to a `class` by using `DataContract` but I can't-do it. If I read them separately then there is no issue.

This is new to me so exploring what is the best approach to do it. Found some links where the suggestion is to go for an individual parameter but want to make sure I am not missing anything here.

Call: `http://{{url}}/Host?host_name=Test&host_zipcode=123&host_id=123`

Working: I can read these parameter values if I read them as an individual parameter.

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/Host")]
public async Task<HostResponse> GetHostInfo([FromUri (Name = "host_name")] string hostName, [FromUri (Name = "host_zipcode")] string hostZipCode, [FromUri(Name = "host_id")] string hostId)
{
}
```

Not Working: When I try to use `class` by using `DataContract`, I can't read it.

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/Host")]
public async Task<HostResponse> GetHostInfo([FromUri] HostInfo hostInfo)
{
}

[DataContract]
public class HostInfo
{
    [DataMember(Name = "host_name")]
    public string HostName { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "host_zipcode")]
    public string HostZipCode { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "host_id")]
    public string HostId { get; set; }
}
```

I also tried:

```
public class DeliveryManagerStatus
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "country")]
    public string Country { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "delivery_provider")]
    public string DeliveryProvider { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "job_id")]
    public string JobId { get; set; }
}
```

How can I assign these properties to a class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `IModelBinder` ([details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api)) implementation to parse it. Here is a `DataMember` based example (takes key names from DataMember attribute):

```
public class DataMemberBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public bool BindModel(HttpActionContext actionContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var props = bindingContext.ModelType.GetProperties();
        var result = Activator.CreateInstance(bindingContext.ModelType);
        foreach (var property in props)
        {
            try
            {
                var attributes = property.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DataMemberAttribute), true);
                var key = attributes.Length > 0
                    ? ((DataMemberAttribute)attributes[0]).Name
                    : property.Name;
                if (bindingContext.ValueProvider.ContainsPrefix(key))
                {
                    var value = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(key).ConvertTo(property.PropertyType);
                    property.SetValue(result, value);
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                // log that property can't be set or throw an exception
            }
        }
        bindingContext.Model = result;
        return true;
    }
}
```

and usage

```
public async Task<HostResponse> GetHostInfo([FromUri(BinderType = typeof(DataMemberBinder))] HostInfo hostInfo)
```

In quick search I wasn't able to find any AttributeBased binder try and share if you will find it

Comment: IModelBinder not support in net 6 minimal api

Answer (score 0):

Using your HostInfo class change your call to:

`http://{{url}}/Host?hostInfo.host_name=Test&hostInfo.host_zipcode=123&hostInfo.host_id=123`.

I would recommend changing your route to accept the complex type in the body if possible due to the limitations in query string length.